# is there a way to re-stream HLS (m3u8) files so the connections only hit my server and the server streams a re-rendered one, not the original stream?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

BTW, I am still a beginner in back-end development and I am not sure if this is even a realistic question but I am considering this as a last hope anyway...

The main problem is that the main server that serves the m3u8 files URLs I want to send to the client is only available to connect to a maximum of 3 devices per URL,
I was thinking if I can work around this by creating a node server app witch somehow always keep reading the stream and then when a request hit my server the client gets the regenerated stream URL from my server and not the original one that has the limitations...

I hope this doesn't sound stupid :))..

Comment: Why can it only do 3 devices? You should use a different server or change its settings.

Comment: All the free ones have limits like this, and I can not afford to get a paid subscription because I am almost broke =( ...

Comment: Which free one are you using? Are you hosting this yourself? Even if you wrote some node app to proxy the URLs it would have to be hosted somewhere and that's rarely free (though cheap options are available).

Comment: I am getting the URLs from a provider called (vtpii) which have free plans,  they just provide playlists for the self-use to play the streams on a media player like VLC for example, the current problem I am facing is the connections limit thing, I'll worry about hosting my own server app later ..

Answer (score 0):

HLS streaming is just HTTP.  There's nothing more to it.

You don't need Node.js for this at all.  Any caching proxy server will do.  You could use Nginx, for example.  https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

Something like this:

```
server {
  location / {
    proxy_cache hls_cache;
    proxy_cache_revalidate off;
    proxy_cache_lock on;
    proxy_pass https://your-stream-server.example.com;
  }
}
```